# failed - server error laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file, download, filesystems

i'm trying to download file in my application but getting failed - server problem error.

Here's the URL in my view:

```
    <a href="{{route('download',$value->file)}}" download="{{$value->file}}" class=" btn btn-info btn-sm">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"> Download</i>
    </a>
```

my route:

```
Route::get('/download/{filename}','HrController@downloadFile')->name('download');
```

my download function:

```
public function downloadFile($filename)
    {
           $dwn = storage_path('app\public\upload'.$filename);
            return Storage::download($dwn);
    }
```

an image showing the error message i'm getting
[link to the image showing the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddn6R.png)

Comment: Where's the image you promised? Show us the error message.

Comment: Solved this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a form in order to transfert files.  You can use Laravel collective to create a form. You can find more information here:

https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#file-input

Don't forget to add files in opening your form :

{!! Form::open(['url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true]) !!}

Comment: i'm downloading file not transfer

Comment: Ok sorry I didn't well understand your answer